# Script CreateUser.sql in BatchFile

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch script that open a CMD and connect to Oracle Server (with SQLPlus) with command line parameters for user, password and SID.

After connection, I want to run a script. In this case `@CreateUser.sql`:

```
CREATE USER TEST IDENTIFIED BY TEST
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;
```

But it doesn't work.

```
@echo off
@echo off
setlocal
start cmd.exe /k "net use"
if "%~1"=="" goto :error empty 1
if "%~2"=="" goto :error empty 2
if "%~3"=="" goto :error empty 3
set "username=%~1"
if not exist "%username%\" goto :error not exist 1
set "password=%~2"
if not exist "%password%\" goto :error not exist 2
set "SID=%~3"
if not exist "%SID%\" goto :error not exist 3
sqlplus "%username%"/"%password%"@"%SID%" @CreateUser.sql
goto :eof
:error
echo wrong parameters %*
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
@echo off
setlocal
set /P ORCL=Enter server or service_name:
set /P UN=Enter DB User:
set /P PWD=Enter password for DB user:
sqlplus "%UN%/%PWD%@%ORCL%" @CreateUser.sql
```

I solved this. Now I have a problem with the name for user. I want to pass as command line argument the username from CreateUser.sql.

CREATE USER $Username IDENTIFIED BY $UserPassword DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;

How can i do that?

```
@echo off
@echo off
setlocal
set /P ORCL=Enter server or service_name:
set /P UN=Enter DB User:
set /P PWD=Enter password for DB user:
set /P User=Enter name for user:
set /P Password=Enter password for user:
sqlplus "%UN%/%PWD%@%ORCL%" @CreateUser.sql "%User%" "%Password%"
```

Thank you.

Comment: See [this page](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus.html) for sqlplus syntax.  Within CreateUser.sql, `&1` will be `%User%` and `&2` will be `%Password%`.